# Mean of a column only for observations meeting a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I add a column with the mean of z for each group "y" for values where if x < 10 for any other case the mean column can take the value of z?

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[1:5],LETTERS[3:7]), x = 1:15, z = c(4:9,1:4,2:6))
```

```
   y  x z
1  A  1 4
2  B  2 5
3  C  3 6
4  D  4 7
5  E  5 8
6  A  6 9
7  B  7 1
8  C  8 2
9  D  9 3
10 E 10 4
11 C 11 2
12 D 12 3
13 E 13 4
14 F 14 5
```

I am trying something like

```
df %>% group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(gr.mean = mean(z))
```

But this provides the mean for any case of x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the 'z' with a logical condition on 'x':

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(y) %>%
      mutate(gr.mean = if(all(x >=10)) z else mean(z[x < 10])) %>%
      ungroup
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   y         x     z gr.mean
   <chr> <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1 A         1     4     6.5
 2 B         2     5     3
 3 C         3     6     4
 4 D         4     7     5
 5 E         5     8     8
 6 A         6     9     6.5
 7 B         7     1     3
 8 C         8     2     4
 9 D         9     3     5
10 E        10     4     8
11 C        11     2     4
12 D        12     3     5
13 E        13     4     8
14 F        14     5     5
15 G        15     6     6
```

---

Or without `if/else`

```
df %>%
     group_by(y) %>%
      mutate(gr.mean = coalesce(mean(z[x < 10]), z))
```

Comment: hhh... but this is works, except it also provide values to grouped mean to to places where x>= 10, but I guess I can fix that from here by adding an ifelse

Comment: @Macosso There is a `if` condition if you check my update which returns `NA` where the values are only x >= 10 in a group

Comment: yep, also was able to do it like this ```df %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(gr.mean = if_else(x<10, mean(z[x < 10]), as.double(z)))```

Comment: @Macosso you may also do `coalesce(mean(z[x < 10]), z)`